# Operational Amplifier Driving Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, rfid

I am trying to do this circuit like screenshot. Why we need this highlighted part? What is the purpose? Is it filter or driving part of the amplifier? Please explain.

[image: RFID Receiver Front-End schematic from LT1994 datasheet]

image is taken from [LT1994 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1994fb.pdf).

Comment: bb0667 - Hi, Thanks for mentioning the image source in text. However the [site rule](/help/referencing) requires a *link* to the source for copied or adapted content. Therefore in order to help, I found & added that for you. Please include the name & webpage or PDF link for online sources in future (or add a normal, full citation for books or other offline sources). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Those are low-pass networks.  I'm assuming that the RF and LO frequencies are nominally equal in that schematic, with the intent of generating an I/Q output at baseband.

Here's one of them, picked out to highlight what they're doing.  Keep in mind that the 5V supply is (or should be) a ground at RF:

[image]

The LT5575 will generate I and Q signals that have spectral content at \$f_{RF} - f_{LO}\$ and \$f_{RF} + f_{LO}\$.  If you're generating a low-frequency I/Q signal pair, then you want \$f_{RF} - f_{LO}\$, but you want to reject the \$f_{RF} + f_{LO}\$.  Preferably, you want to reject those signals before they hit the op-amps and possibly cause distortion.

Comment: like a pi filter?

Comment: Edit made to answer.